# Missing/lost first character reading serial data from com port to excel

Tags: excel, vba, serial-port

I have a measuring device attached to a Heidenhain ND221 display which can send it´s current value over RS232 serial data. I would like to read that data via excel vba to do some calculations. From the datasheet I know the serial settings (9600,E,7,2) and a terminal like putty displays the data correctly: "-___x.xxxx" (4 spaces between +/- and value)

I used the vba code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569698/what-is-the-best-way-to-access-a-serial-port-from-vba)

```
#If VBA7 Then ' Excel 2010 or later
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As LongPtr)
#Else ' Excel 2007 or earlier
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As Long)
#End If

Public Sub SerialPort()
    ' open a COM port, transmit a message, gather results, close the port.

    ' open the COM port as file #1
    Debug.Print "Open COM port 3"
    Open "COM3:9600,E,7,2" For Binary Access Read Write As #1

    transmit$ = Chr(2)

    ' transmit a message
    Put #1, , transmit$
    Debug.Print "Message sent."

    ' wait a bit for a response
    Sleep 100

    ' check for received message
    Debug.Print "Look for incoming message."
    On Error Resume Next

    Input #1, receive$
    Debug.Print receive$

    On Error GoTo 0

    ' close the serial port
    Debug.Print "Close COM port."
    Close #1

    Debug.Print "Done."
End Sub
```

I do receive data but it is missing the positiv or negative sign while still reading the 4 spaces in front.
Is it the serial port configuration or the input # statement and how can I fix it?
I also tried `Get` and `Line Input` with the same result.

Thanks!

Comment: The display is triggered by Ctrl+B or STX = Chr(2) to send its data. That works flawlessly. Debug.Print does not work with transmit$ since it is no printable character.

Answer (score 1):

ok, I found a workaround. I changed

```
input #1, receive$
```

to

```
Dim receive As String
receive = String(11, " ")
Get #1, , receive
```

The Get # statement did not show any data until I added the two lines before. (I know the data always has exactly 11 digits).

However initialisiing the receive variable as a string did not fix the Input # statement.

Only problem now is that the code freezes if you try to receive data while there is none available. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52729410/read-serial-port-using-the-get-comfile-record-in-excel-vba-seems-to-have-a).
For example if the display is switched off the com port still exists and can be opened. So far I found no way the check if get will fail before doing so. And once it tries it cannot be stopped or timed out.